# Alter Query Taking A Long Time

Tags: postgresql, locking, ddl

I just tried to add a column to one table in my database but it is taking forever.

```
alter table xxx add column frame_weight float;
```

I looked around and it appeared there might be locks. I tried the below mentioned steps.

```
select * from pg_locks ;

 locktype  | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid  |      mode       | granted | fastpath 
-----------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+-------+-----------------+---------+----------
relation   |    16387 |    60737 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 3/136193           | 17977 | AccessShareLock | t       | t
relation   |    16387 |    60748 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 3/136193           | 17977 | AccessShareLock | t       | t
relation   |    16387 |    60781 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 3/136193           | 17977 | AccessShareLock | t       | t
relation   |    16387 |    60733 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 3/136193           | 17977 | AccessShareLock | t       | t
relation   |    16387 |    60774 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 3/136193           | 17977 | AccessShareLock | t       | t
virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 3/136193   |               |         |       |          | 3/136193           | 17977 | ExclusiveLock   | t       | t
relation   |    16387 |    11069 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 2/4820             | 20752 | AccessShareLock | t       | t
virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 2/4820     |               |         |       |          | 2/4820             | 20752 | ExclusiveLock   | t       | t
relation   |    16387 |    60741 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 3/136193           | 17977 | AccessShareLock | t       | f

select * from pg_stat_activity where pid = 17977;

 datid | datname |  pid  | usesysid | usename | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         |          xact_start           |          query_start          |         state_change          | waiting | state  | query                                                
-------+---------+-------+----------+---------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+--------+--------
 16387 | xx      | 17977 |    16385 | xx      |                  | 127.0.0.1   |                 |       50626 | 2018-05-10 20:13:06.001069-04 | 2018-05-10 20:13:06.251093-04 | 2018-05-10 20:13:06.251369-04 | 2018-05-10 20:13:06.251372-04 | f       | active | SELECT  

select pg_cancel_backend (17977);
pg_cancel_backend 
-------------------
 t
(1 row)
```

then I gave the terminate command -

```
select pg_terminate_backend (17977);
 pg_terminate_backend 
----------------------
 t
(1 row)
```

After trying all this the alter command is still taking a long time. Can somebody please suggest what might be wrong??

If you do not like this question, please do not downvote. Simply tell me and I will remove it. I am an absolute beginner and downvoting hurts me badly in contributing or learning with this community. Thanks!

Best

Comment: So what is the exact command you are running? In what state was the session in which you ran the `ALTER TABLE` was it waiting?

Comment: This is the command - alter table xxx add column frame_weight float; After entering this command, it just waits for a long time and nothing happens. This should not take a long time because I am not populating. It merely updates the metadata for the table.

Comment: Also, how did you edit my post? How did you make my tables appear better? Please tell me so I can do it myself next time. Thanks!

Comment: Indent with four spaces to have text appear in a code box. Also use the right lengths for the lines etc..

Comment: Click on the `edit` link below the question to edit your question. Click on the question mark on the upper right corner while editing to get [help on formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: So did you check if what the state (`pg_stat_activity.state`) of the session is where you run the statement?

Comment: Could you please describe what do you mean by the state of the session? How do I find that out?

Comment: I think the problem is resolved. I had to ask admin to kill the "pid" using linux terminal. After that I ran alter table query and it worked. Thanks!